# Exporting single sheet to HTML

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to export a single sheet (not the whole workbook) as HTML using VBA.

When I record a macro exporting to HTML a single sheet, I get this code:

```
Range("C36").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= _
    "Macintosh HD:Users:user:Desktop:Dashboard.htm", FileFormat:=xlHtml, _
    PublishOption:=xlSheet
```

And the exported HTML only contains the sheet I wanted, so everything's fine till this point.

The problem comes when I try to run the code, it creates an HTML file that contains the whole workbook and not only the sheet I wanted.

I've looked at [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.14).aspx), and the `SaveAs` method doesn't seem to have a `PublishOption` parameter.

Any clues?